# FLUTTER: Wait for cloud function to finish and check outcome in client

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, square

Trying to use square payment processor.

1. Clients request a nonce from Square SDK
2. Client writes nonce to cloud firestore
3. Server create a card customer and writes result to DB (can be success or error)
4. My question: how to await for 3) in the client and proceed accordingly?

   Future awaitServerWrite(
       String controlField,
       dynamic passCondition,
       Duration timeout,   ) {
       print('waiting on server write');
       Completer completer = Completer();
       StreamSubscription stream;
       Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch()..start();

   ```
   stream = ref.snapshots().listen((snap) {
     if (snap.data[controlField] != null) {
       if (snap.data[controlField] == passCondition) {
         stream.cancel();
         completer.complete(true);
       } else {
         completer.complete(false);
       }
     }

     if (timer.elapsedMilliseconds > timeout.inMilliseconds) {
       print('operation timeout');
       completer.complete(false);
     }
     print('no controlField ($controlField) in snap...');
     completer.future;
   });

   print('waiting data....');
   return completer.future;   }
   ```

Is my logic correct? Is this the code even correct?? Could i make this simpler?

Thank you. Im a beginner.